# Move vertex with Prop Edit, moves the entire objec

Tags: modeling

I have a problem, that another post did not answer for me.  On my sphere, (total newbie doing Zachs apples still life videos)  when I select the top vertex of the sphere, and move it downward, it works fine without proportional editing, BUT once I click on Proportional editing, then the entire sphere moves

I have tried using the scroll wheel to lower size of the circle of influence, but usually  it just makes the sphere itself smaller. Also used pg down, no luck

I have 2.9.0 and also do not see the size of the circle at bottom of viewport, which many answers said is there.  Not in my 2.9   I made the sphere have radius of 5cm.  Note when I try this same procedure with the default size of the sphere, it works fine.  Bu if I start new, change the size, then I have the problem

I'd appreciate any help.  Thank you

Comment: Have you noticed that proportional editing size is displayed on the 3D view itself in 2.9, on its top? Do you have it displayed? If the sphere is 5cm and you've zoom in maybe you won't see the prop edit circle.

Comment: No I do not see the size anywhere in the viewport, top or bottom. Even toggling it on and off, I notice no change on top or bottom.

Comment: When I hold left button down and scroll the wheel the size of the sphere keeps getting smaller and smaller. I don't think that's whats supposed to happen.  Sort of checkmated with this.  Thanks

Comment: Which sphere is getting smaller in the case you described? The sphere mesh model or the propotional editing circle?

Comment: The sphere mesh model keeps getting smaller

Comment: Solved, not sure what I was doing wrong, but I think I got the procedure down now.  Cockpit error, not surprisingly.  Thanks for the input